# .Net MVC, how to call Javascript function in external Javascript file from partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a Partial view that I want to call a jQuery function that resides in an external Javascript file.  I know partial views can possibly rendered multiple times on a parent view, I am OK with this.  For our case the partial view only renders once in any case.  I call the external Javascript file reference in the parent of the Partial View.

I have an external Javascript file 'global.js' with a function in it.

```
  //function in global.js
  function myFunction(){alert("hello");}
```

In my partial view I have a script tag that I want to call the "myFunction" function in the global.js file.

```
   <script>myFunction();</script>
```

Should be pretty standard stuff, but when I try to call "myFunction()" from the partial view in my Chrome Developer Console, I get that myFunction() is not defined.  Like I mentioned, it is called in the parent of the partial view, but it seems the Partial View doesn't have any idea the external Javascript file exists.

Any recommendations?

Comment: If this global.js is declared in the default template, it should work

Comment: Could you show the rendered html code?

Answer (score 0):

thjis is because your script file is loaded after your partial view

something like

```
<head>
<body>
Your Partial view 
script inside partial view 

@juqry render (inculding global js)
</body>
```

to fix this the best would be render the @script.Render() in the head section of yourr _layout

Answer (score 0):

Check that your script appears after the declaration of your global.js in your rendered file.

Assuming you are using the standard templating you should be able put the script portion in your partial view within an mvc @section like this;

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
         myFunction();

    </script>

}
```

MVC will then place this code where

```
@RenderSection("script", required:false)
```

Appears in your _layout.cshtml.